# Bash quitar del nombre del fichero texto

Tags: linux, bash, archivo

Tengo una estructura de carpetas y ficheros como sigue:

```
A    AA.VV
       Encuentro con Medusa - AA. VV_.azw3
     Abbi Glines
       1.Existence.Existence
          1.Existence.Existence - Abby Glines.pdf
       2.Predestined.Existence
          2.Predestined.Existence - Abbi Glines.pdf
     Adam Nevil
       Adam Nevill - Fin De Los Dias, El.mobi
     Alejandra Balsa
       alejandra balsa - promesas incumplidas (el secreto de puente    viejo).pdf
B
     B Amann
       Amor entre acertijos - B. Amann.pdf
     Barb Capisce
       Barb Capisce - Perdóname. Ángel Prohibido 06.epub
     Becca Fitzpatrick
       4.Finale.hush hush
          4.Finale.hush hush - Becca Fitzpatrick.pdf
:   :
:   :
:
└── Y
    ├── Yasmina Khadra
    │   ├── Lo que sueñan los lobos - Yasmina Khadra
    └── Yolanda Revuelta
        ├── Preludios del Pasado.epub][1]][1]
```

y quisiera eliminar del nombre del fichero el nombre de la carpeta que lo contiene.

Con la siguiente linea:

```
for file in */*; do echo ${file#*/*}; done
```

Consigo el nombre de la carpeta que contiene los ficheros.

```
AA. VV.
Abbi Glines
Adam Nevil
Alejandra Balsa
Alex George
:
:
```

Ahora es necesario ir buscando por todo el arbol de carpetas los ficheros que contenga y si tienen en el nombre el nombre de la carpeta que lo contiene renombrar el fichero quitando el nombre de la carpeta.

Con esta linea:

```
find -type f -exec bash -c 'fp=$(dirname "${1#*/*/}"); echo "${fp%/*}"' sh "{}" \;
```

Encontramos los ficheros con el nombre de la carpeta que lo contiene.

Esto es lo que se debe buscar dentro del nombre del fichero y eliminarlo.

¿Cómo se podría combinar ambas líneas para que, de manera recursiva, se realizara dicha acción?

Gracias, o si hubiera otra manera mas sencilla se agradecería la ayuda.

Comment: Hay inconsistencias; en `AA.VV` tienes `AA. VV` (hay un espacio), en `B Amann` tienes `B. Amann` (hay un punto). No queda claro qué pasaría con los guiones y espacios "sobrantes", ¿Podrías agregar a tu pregunta el ejemplo del resultado esperado? Es deseable un script para generar la estructura de archivos.

Comment: Gracias, las inconsistencias se asumen por ser una estructura de carpetas y ficheros recopilados de una carpeta en la que  estaban todos todos juntos (ficheros). El resultado esperado es eliminar del nombre del fichero la parte que coincide con el nombre de la carpeta que lo contiene ( no la subcarpeta). Ejemplo: A/Anton B/Obras literarias - Anton B.pdf ===> y deberia quedar: A/Anton B/Obras literarias.pdf .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Archivo bash: `./cleanfilenames.sh`

```sh
#! /bin/bash

for full_dir in */*; do
    # '-d' for directory only
    if [[ -d "${full_dir}" ]]; then
        dir_name="${full_dir##*/}"
        echo "full_dir: <${full_dir}>, dir_name: <${dir_name}>"
        idx=1
        for full_file in "${full_dir}/"*; do
            # '-f' for standard file only
            if [[ -f "${full_file}" ]]; then
                file_name="${full_file##*/}"
                echo " |- full_file: <${full_file}>, file_name: <${file_name}>, ext: <${file_name#*.}>"
                # 'grep' with '-i' for all cases
                if grep -i "${dir_name}" < <(echo -n "${file_name}") >/dev/null 2>&1; then
                    # 'sed' with 'g' all occurences and 'I' for all cases
                    # remove also spaces and minus chars before and after dir name (it's pretty)
                    new_file_name=$(echo -n "${file_name}" | sed -e "s/[- ]*${dir_name}[- ]*//gI")
                    # check empty new name
                    if [[ "${new_file_name}" == ".${file_name#*.}" ]]; then
                        new_file_name="x_${idx}${new_file_name}"
                        idx=$(( idx + 1 ))
                    fi
                    #echo " |   - YES, new_file_name=<${new_file_name}>"
                    echo " |     " mv -n "${full_dir}/${file_name}" "${full_dir}/${new_file_name}"
                else
                    #echo " |   - NO"
                    :
                fi
            fi
        done
    fi
done
```

Ejecutado así:

```sh
./cleanfilenames.sh
```

1. Los directorios se enumeran primero (como con su bucle for).
2. Los archivos estándar de cada directorio se comparan con el nombre del directorio independientemente del caso.
3. Si coincide, se eliminan todas las ocurrencias, así como los espacios y guiones antes y después del patrón.
4. Si el nombre del archivo sin extensión está vacío, agregamos un patrón (aquí "`x`") y un índice para evitar que dos archivos tengan el mismo nombre. Depende de usted cambiar la "`x`" por lo que desee.
5. Se cambia el nombre del archivo. La opción "`-n`" evita sobrescribir un archivo ya presente.
   Puede ejecutar el script tal como está. No hará nada. Si le parece bien, elimine el "`echo " |     "` " delante del comando" `mv`".

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Funciona bien, aunque falla en algunos ficheros concretos, puede ser por la estructura del nombre del fichero. No lo puse en el ejemplo inicial pero en algunas de las carpetas de autores hay subcarpetas (culpa mia) a las que no llega el script. Supongo que no sera dificil modificarlo para que llege hasta el final de todas las subcarpetas carpetas. a estudiarlo. Gracias muchas.